# Error in sql prepared statement in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have following code in which i m executing select query in php,But i m not aware of prepared statements,Please correct the error in that

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
$lcSearcharr="Baby-Car-Seat";
foreach( $lcSearcharr as $lcSearchWord ){
$lcSearchWord = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $lcSearchWord);
$lcSearchWord = preg_replace('/%/', '\%', $lcSearchWord);
    $parts[] = '`Description` LIKE "%'.$lcSearchWord.'%"';

}


/* create a prepared statement */
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, 'SELECT * FROM xml WHERE  ('.implode ('AND',?).')')) {
    /* bind parameters for markers */
    /* Assumes userid is integer and category is string */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $parts);  
    /* execute query */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    /* bind result variables */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt);
    /* fetch value */
    mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
    /* Alternative, use a while:
    while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {

    }

    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}

/* close connection */
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

I have a variable at start having value as baby-car-seat.Then i m exploding them in an array,after then i m executing select query which i m executing using implode function.This query is working correctly without prepared statement but not with prepared statement.Please correct my error where i m wrong.

Comment: Please also post the link to the magic ball which will tell us the error description

Comment: Error almost certainly lies here `implode ('AND',?)`

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky-I m getting error on ? in implode function only,but it works correct with prepared statement.

Comment: see below link which helps you to get your problem fixed. https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$lcSearcharr="Baby-Car-Seat";
foreach( $lcSearcharr as $lcSearchWord ){
$lcSearchWord = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $lcSearchWord);
$lcSearchWord = preg_replace('/%/', '\%', $lcSearchWord);
    $parts[] = $lcSearchWord;

}

$search = implode('|',$parts);

if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, 'SELECT * FROM xml WHERE Description REGEXP ?'))
{
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $search);  
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
}

mysqli_close($link);
```

This uses `REGEX` to check through the `Description` column.

Or

```
$lcSearcharr="Baby-Car-Seat";
foreach( $lcSearcharr as $lcSearchWord ){
$lcSearchWord = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $lcSearchWord);
$lcSearchWord = preg_replace('/%/', '\%', $lcSearchWord);
    $parts[] = "%$lcSearchWord%";

}

$countSearchWords = count($parts);

$str = str_repeat('s', $countSearchWords); 

$q = array_fill(0,$countSearchWords,'Description LIKE ?');
$params = implode(' AND ',$q);

if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, 'SELECT * FROM xml WHERE '.$params))
{
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, $str, $parts);  
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
}

mysqli_close($link);
```

This will do what you were trying to do. by adding `$parts` and `$params` separately.

`('.implode ('AND',?).')` is invalid syntax. you can not use `?` like that.